# Compelex Flex Box Layout

Tags: css, flexbox

I am attempting to create a full screen app interface. There should be a scrolling area in the region named 'view-with-wisdebar'. The 'content' area should also scroll so the 'options' remain static.

I am approximating the flexible height using viewport units on one of the flex box descendants. The header should be static. The main should have a flexible height with scrolling area inside it. The footer should be static.

The problem is that the contents never matches the viewport height. The 'overflow auto' element is not used. I thought I had achieved this but then I added some more header height and footer went off the bottom!

As you can see I want the header and footer fixed to the top and bottom, and I want the middle section flexible. The middle section should contain aa fixed height navbar and a flexible view area.

https://jsfiddle.net/p47o5yfe/6/

-- edit: A second link to show the desired effect approximately

https://jsfiddle.net/p47o5yfe/8/

-- edit: I have simplified the problem further

https://jsfiddle.net/p47o5yfe/10/

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

main {}

.view-controller {}

.navbar {}

.view-with-sidebar {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  overflow: auto;
  height: calc(100vh - 300px);
}

.sidebar {
  width: 100px;
}

.view {
  width: 100%;
}

.options {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.content {
  overflow-x: auto;
}

footer {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header class="header">
    Header
  </header>
  <main>
    <div class="view-controller">
      <div class="navbar">
        Navbar
        <div class="view-with-sidebar">
          <div class="sidebar">
            Sidebar
          </div>
          <div class="view">
            <div class="options">
              Options
            </div>
            <div class="content">
              Content
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </main>
  <footer>
    Footer
  </footer>
  </div>
```

Comment: I actually answered my post saying I fixed this however that is not true. I have hacked it using calc (viewport height - fixed height) https://jsfiddle.net/p47o5yfe/12/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to put scrollbar only on content and option div (without any hardcore) you could do something like this. I didn't change your HTML, I worked only with CSS. They are all commented to make it simple to understand.

```css
* {
    /* it is better if you use a normalize css (https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) instead of these rules that I added only for this example */
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    /* end */
}

.wrapper,
.wrapper * {
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 2px;
    background-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5) !important;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0; /* add this to remove the default scrollbar, you can remove this rule if it is not a problem for you */
    height: 100vh;
}

.header {
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}

main {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    overflow-y: hidden; /* add this rule to use the last level overflow-y in content & options */
}

footer {
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}

.view-controller {
    display: flex; /* it is a flexbox in a flexbox in a flexbox... */
    flex-direction: column;
}

.view-with-sidebar {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    display: flex;
    overflow-y: hidden; /* add this rule to use the last level overflow-y in content & options */
}

.sidebar {
    width: 100px;
}

.view {
    display: flex; /* another flexbox in a flexbox... the game continues... */
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.options {
    margin-right: 10px;
    min-width: 100px; /* this is an add only to read better the options content, you can remove it */
    overflow-y: auto; /* this is the real overflow with scroll bar */
}

.content {
    overflow-y: auto; /* this is the real overflow with scroll bar */
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
      <header>
        Header<br>
        Header
      </header>
      <main class="view-controller">
           <div class="navbar">
                Navbar<br>
                Navbar
           </div>
          <div class="view-with-sidebar">
           <div class="sidebar">
              Sidebar<br>
              Sidebar
            </div>
            <div class="view">
              <div class="options">
                Options<br>
                Options<br>
                Options<br>
                Options<br>
                Options<br>
                Options<br>
                Options<br>
                Options<br>
                Options<br>
                Options<br>
                Options<br>
                Options<br>
               </div>
              <div class="content">
                Content<br> Content
                <br> Content
                <br> Content
                <br> Content
                <br> Content
                <br> Content
                <br> Content
                <br> Content
                <br> Content
                <br> Content
                <br> Content
                <br> Content
                <br> Content
                <br> Content
                <br> Content
                <br> Content
                <br> Content
                <br> Content
                <br> Content
                <br> Content
                <br> Content
                <br> Content
                <br> Content
                <br> Content
                <br> Content
                <br> Content
                <br> Content
                <br> Content
                <br> Content
                <br> Content
                <br> Content
                <br>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </main>
      <footer>
        Footer<br>
        Footer</footer>
    </div>
```